# Perform calculation in Excel with 2 table comparison

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

I have 2 tables: SheetA!D5:F15, with Column D containing date and time, and Column F containing values. Table 2: `SheetB!C5:D100`, with Column C containing Date and Time and Column D contain values.

I want to perform some calculation (for example, add values together) on SheetA column G with values of Column F in SheetA and values in column D of SheetB if corresponding date and time of sheetB is equal or less than date and time of sheetA.

In the example I attached below, G5 should return `39+30+30+30+30+30+30+30=219` as there are 6 date and time in SheetB that are equal or less than 10/26/16 13:30

I'm thinking vlookup or index match, but not sure the exact details. Greatly appreciate if anyone can provide some details.

SheetA:

[image]

SheetB:

[image]

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far. I suggest you google `SUMIF`. If you cannot figure out I will consider assisting if you promise never again to place a table anywhere else in a worksheet except on the top left corner ;p. No 3 column indent or 3 row header with just empty space. These tend to complicate any future analysis and I would advice against this type of formatting as best practice.